# is it possible to do 1 Advice to multiple PointCut?

Tags: java, spring, aop

For ex: i want to log every behavior in a book class.
Is it possilbe to do it with Spring-AOP?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with bellow expression in `@Around`, for example :

```java
    @Pointcut("execution(* AOPviaAnnotation.Book.*(..))")
    public void allMethodOfBook() {};

    @Around("allMethodOfBook()")
    public void logBookInfo(){
     ...
    }
```

or try with `||`

```java
    @Pointcut("execution(* AOPviaAnnotation.Book.add(..))")
    public void addMethod() {};
    @Pointcut("execution(* AOPviaAnnotation.Book.delete(..))")
    public void deleteMethod() {};

    @Around("addMethod() || deleteMethod()")
    public void logBookInfo(){
     ...
    }
```